# save android app setting to mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, database, sharedpreferences

I'm new to `MySQL` database and past week I was trying to understand sending and receiving data from android app to `MySQL` database. what I'm confused about and tried to find it by google or stackOverFlow or even youtube is that what is the best way to save android app user setting (like leveling up feature for specific user)to `MySQL` database. I can do it easily by shared preference if I had plan to do it locally but I need to save it to online database, so can I save `SharedPreferences` to `MySQL`?. what is the best way ?

Comment: You could look into "Google Firebase"

Comment: @Sajad, storing app preference locally is not preferred. It's good that you are looking for a way to store it in using online database. Just create a table for this particular data and always fetch/select it during app launch/when you need it. Are you facing any issues while trying to do so? If yes, do provide the codes/blocker you are facing.

Comment: How much data of user you want to store

Comment: @juergend sry i forgot to mention im from iran i cant use firebase :(

Comment: @Shaon not much only details like customized theme colors or else

Comment: @user1872384 thx your answer actually showed my some way. what kind of libraries u suggest while connection android app to mysql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to store data online either use a given service or build your own API by implementing a backend you can then communicate with e.g. by https://github.com/square/retrofit with https://github.com/square/okhttp. You could have an API call which you just pass your `SharedPreferences` as `JSON` data and store it in a `MySQL` text type. But of course building your own API for just storing some preferences might be too much effort.